# Allow PDF and/or ZIP Files in Wysiwyg Editor in Magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

Is it possible to allow upload and link PDF/ZIP-files in wysiwyg editor in Magento 2? I found many solutions for Magento 1.x but not for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

This module may help you.

It allows additional file types in the WYSIWYG editor.

https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-WysiwygDownloads